# generic priority queues design in C++

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I am designing a generic priority queue in C++ which can take any data type as key either it can be int or user defined structure. I want to implement priority queue using binary heap, linked lists, bionomial heap, and fibanocci heap. Here user can select any implementation. For some of the functions I should return internal handles to user so that users can pass to priority queue for certain operations to have good performance, for example change function, remove functions, here if we have handle we can have this implementations fast rather than searching.

So I have generic priority interface as shown below

```
template <class Item>
class IMyPriorityQueue {
private:
    /* Implementattion dependent code
       Here we can implement priority queue functions mentioned in public section of class using
       ordered array, unordered array, ordered list, unordered list, heap data structure, 
       bionomial heap and fibonacci heap.  (here list means double linked list).

       Heap means is a tree is heap-ordered if the key in each node is larger than or equal to the keys in all of that node's children (if any).
       Equivalently, the key in each node of a heap-ordered tree is smaller than or equal to the key in that node's parent (if any).

       Read Robert Sedwick on various implementation have performance on Table 9.1 on page .

    */

public:
    // Implementation-dependent handle definition
    IMyPriorityQueue(int);
    virtual ~IMyPriorityQueue();
    virtual int empty() const            = 0;
    virtual handle insert(Item )         = 0;
    virtual int getmax()                 = 0;
    virtual void change(handle, Item)    = 0;
    virtual void remove(handle)          = 0;
    virtual void join(IMyPriorityQueue&) = 0;
};


template <class Item>
class CMyLinkedListPriorityQueue : public IMyPriorityQueue {
private:

    // Implementing using unordered double linked list.
    struct sPQNode {
        Item     pqItem;
        sPQNode* pPrevPQNode;
        sPQNode* pNextPQNode;

        sPQNode(Item itm) {
            pqItem      = itm; 
            pPrevPQNode = 0; 
            pNextPQNode = 0; 
        }
    };

    // Note: here head and tail are it self sPQNode* rather than void* pointer which points to first node.
    sPQNode* m_pPQhead;
    sPQNode* m_pPQTail;

    std::vector<sPQNode*> m_vecPQNodePointer;
    int                   m_iVecContainerIndex;

    CMyLinkedListPriorityQueue(int = 0) {
        m_pPQhead = new sPQNode(0);
        m_pPQTail = new sPQNode(0);
        m_pPQhead->pPrevPQNode = m_pPQTail; m_pPQhead->pNextPQNode = m_pPQTail;
        m_pPQTail->pPrevPQNode = m_pPQhead; m_pPQTail->pNextPQNode = m_pPQhead;
        m_iVecContainerIndex  = 0;
    }

    int empty() const {
        return m_pPQhead->pNextPQNode->pNextPQNode == m_pPQhead;
        m_iVecContainerIndex = 0;
    }

    handle insert(Item v) {
        handle insPQNode = new node(v);
        insPQNode->pNextPQNode = m_pPQhead->pNextPQNode; insPQNode->pNextPQNode->pPrevPQNode = insPQNode;
        insPQNode->pPrevPQNode = m_pPQhead; m_pPQhead->pNextPQNode = insPQNode;
        m_vecPQNodePointer[m_iVecContainerIndex++] = insPQNode
        return (m_iVecContainerIndex - 1);
    }

    Item getmax() {
        Item max; sPQNode* pHeadNext = head->next;
        for (link t = x; t->next != head; t = t->next) {
            if (x->item < t->item) x = t;
        }
        max = x->item;
        remove(x);
        return max;
    }

    void change(handle hItem, Item itm) {
        m_iVecContainerIndex[hItem]->item = itm;
    }

    void remove(handle hItem) {
                // **Question how to handle this and join operation**
                 }

    void join(PQ<Item>& p) {
        tail->prev->next = p.head->next;
        p.head->next->prev = tail->prev;
        head->prev = p.tail;
        p.tail->next = head;
        delete tail; delete p.head;
        tail = p.tail;
     }
};
```

Problem I am facing with above design if we remove an item and empty that particular location I am making that entry in vector to null, but problem is that vector size is growing as program runs for long time. I can think of use of map container but again this will search again. I want to avoid search during remove, join and change operations.

Any better design to handle above scenario.

Thanks for your inputs

Comment: Jack of all trades, master of none:(

Comment: I don't understand your design well enough, so ignoring your code and just looking at your question, there are two common approaches to that issue:  1) When you remove an item, move the last item to the place you removed the item from.  So the last position becomes free and you can truncate the vector (size goes down but generally reserve size does not).  That is more common and simpler, but might break your "handle" idea.  2) Use reinterpret casts on the unused positions to link them together in a free list.  Then pull from the free list first, before extending the vector, when inserting.

Comment: Not that it should stop you, but are you aware that there is already a generic priority queue in C++: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue ?

Comment: @I want to implement one my self

Comment: What purpose does that vector serve?  Why is the handle an index rather than a void* ?  The most common use of "handle" in programming is a pointer that the client isn't supposed to understand as a pointer.  That is most easily done with `typedef void* handle`.  If you just return a disguised sPQNode* as the handle, there may be no need for that vector.  The purpose of a handle is something your code can later easily translate into an sPQNode*